# Getting the GameObject's Script using GetComponent by using a string of the script's name (or not)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a gun/weapon system that allows me to be more flexible by using one script that contains "the shooting mechanics of that specific weapon" **per gun** instead of one script for all gun (because the weapons I'm making has its own characteristics).

what I did was:

Basically I have 3 main scripts,

1. the script from the player that acts as the input (**on the player's game object**)
2. the script that holds the script for shooting mechanic for left and right mouse button (**on the weapon game object**)
3. the script that does the shooting mechanics (**on the weapon**)

I have a script for the player itself (for the weapon controls),  so when the player click LMB it will get the current weapon that it's holding, then get the first weapon script (**1st**) that holds the other shooting mechanic scrips (**2nd**) and then run a function which is "LMB()", that runs a function inside the 3rd script which is to shoot (**3rd**).

1st script

```
public class PlayerShooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] WeaponList;
    public int ListLength;

    public int currentWeapon;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        ListLength = WeaponList.Length;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            // get the 2nd script for the current weapon and runs "LMB()"
        }
    }
}
```

2nd script

```
    public class WeaponScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject selfRef;
    public int WeaponId;


    public void LMB()
    {
        //I don't understand this one
        //var type = Type.GetType(WeaponId + "LMB");
        //selfRef.GetComponent(type);

        // or maybe?
        //selfRef.GetComponent<WeaponId + "LMB">().shoot();
    }
}
```

3rd script

```
public void shoot()
{
    //the shooting happens
}
```

I'm sorry if it confuses you, feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about having an intermediate class for shooting behaviors?

```
public abstract class WeaponScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public virtual void PrimaryFire(){}
    public virtual void SecondaryFire(){}
}
```

Then derive e.g.

```
public class LaserScript: WeaponScript {
    public override void PrimaryFire() { /* pew pew! */ }
}
```

and attach that to your laser gun.

You should then be able to

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)) {
    // Get the first weapon script attached to the weapon
    var weaponScript = WeaponList[currentWeapon].GetComponent<WeaponScript>();
    weaponScript.PrimaryFire();
}
```

Comment: Assets\Player\Gun\WeaponScript.cs(14,26): error CS0506: 'MakeshiftRifle.PrimaryFire()': cannot override inherited member 'WeaponScript.PrimaryFire()' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override | **even though I have the abstract in WeaponScript.**

Comment: after some messing around it worked nicely!, **though I don't know what I did lmao**

Comment: Oops, yeah, I added the missing `virtual`s